# Crossover two individuals of different lengths

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I have two individuals I need to perform crossover on that are of different lengths.

The individuals may be like this, but could be much longer:

0 1 2 2 1 2 0 [0] 1 2 1 2 0 1 2 [0] 1 2 1 2 0 2 1 [1]

1 2 1 1 0 2 0 [0] 1 2 1 2 0 0 1 [1]

However, I need to keep their original length after crossover. I also need to ensure that every 8th bit (in square brackets) cannot be a 2. The length of each individual will always be multiples of 8.

How can I perform crossover on these individuals without changing the length and structure of either individual?

I haven't been able to find a solution to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're talking about a [single-point crossover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_(genetic_algorithm)#Single-point_crossover). You could do something like this:

1. Select a random number between 1 and the length of the **shorter** individual. This will be your crossover point.
2. Cut **both** individuals at this point.
3. Swap them, as per regular crossover.

Example:

```
0 1 2 2 1 2 0 [0] 1 2 1 2 0 1 2 [0] 1 2 1 2 0 2 1 [1]
1 2 1 1 0 2 0 [0] 1 2 1 2 0 0 1 [1]
```

The shorter individual has length **16**, so we generate a random number between 1 and 16 --> e.g., **9**

Crossover point:

```
                   |
0 1 2 2 1 2 0 [0] 1|2 1 2 0 1 2 [0] 1 2 1 2 0 2 1 [1]
1 2 1 1 0 2 0 [0] 1|2 1 2 0 0 1 [1]
                   |
```

Swap sub-sections after the point:

```
                   |
0 1 2 2 1 2 0 [0] 1|2 1 2 0 0 1 [1]
1 2 1 1 0 2 0 [0] 1|2 1 2 0 1 2 [0] 1 2 1 2 0 2 1 [1]
                   |
```

This preserves the length of both individuals, and preserves the no-2s-in-brackets rule.

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this type of solution:
it works (but different cross-over location:

the code is in python

from random import choices, randint, randrange, random

```
a = [1,2,4,5,8,11,3,4,7,2,4,6]
b = [3,4,5,6,9,1,3,6,7]
length_a =len(a)
length_b = len(b)
crossover_prob = 0.8
p = randint(1, length_a - 1) 
q = randint(1, length_b -1)
while p < crossover_prob:
    c = a[0:p] + b[q:]
    
while q < crossover_prob:
    d = b[0:q] + a[p:]



print (c)
print (d)
```

result:

[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 1, 3, 6, 7]
[2, 4, 5, 8, 11, 3, 4, 7, 2, 4, 6]